# What's the difference between the following two lines of C code?

Tags: pointers, declaration

What is the difference between the following lines:

```
\\1:
(int*) args;

\\2:
int *args;
```

Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The first statement casts the existing variable `args` to an `int*`, which means it is not a statement in and of itself. The second statement declares a variable `args` of type `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is an [*explicit cast*](https://www.improgrammer.net/type-casting-c-language/amp/). Specifically, it casts `args` to an `int*`, a pointer to an `int`.

The second statement just declares a variable named `args` as a pointer to an `int`.